# Memory Statistics from Debug class for android

Tags: android, memory-management

The Debug class provides several methods for memory analysis.
from these,

what is the meaning of
GlobalAllocCount and GlobalAllocSize?

-Earlence

Comment: I would like to know the same thing, there is no documentation about these values.